# XMLStreamReader skips elements

Tags: xml, stax, xmlstreamreader

I am trying to analyse wikipedia articles from dump. The file `zhwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml` is a huge XML file. I decided to use `XMLStreamReader` to read the file and import to the database.

The problems is XMLStreamReader does not recognize some `StartElement`. I need that to extract element text. For example a document like

```
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8/" xmlns:xsi="http://ww
w.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/x
ml/export-0.8/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.8.xsd" version="0.8" xml:la
ng="zh">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>Wikipedia</sitename>
    <base>http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5</base>
    <generator>MediaWiki 1.23wmf12</generator>
    <case>first-letter</case>
    <namespaces>
      <namespace key="-2" case="first-letter">Media</namespace>
      <namespace key="-1" case="first-letter">Special</namespace>
      <namespace key="0" case="first-letter" />
    </namespaces>
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>Wikipedia:Upload log</title>
    <ns>4</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <revision>
      <id>15649431</id>
      <parentid>11154293</parentid>
      <timestamp>2011-02-05T03:58:02Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>AT</username>
        <id>248442</id>
      </contributor>
      <minor />
      <comment>[[Wikipedia:Upload log]]已被解除保护: 已保護一段長時間</comment>
      <text xml:space="preserve">...(some long text)</text>
      <sha1>prk62t3ad743sf0ighsrje6vu30qx88</sha1>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
    </revision>
  </page>
</mediawiki>
```

elements like `siteinfo` and `title` could not show up in `streamReader.next()` with `streamReader.isStartElement()` as condition.

Here is my code

```
    XMLInputFactory inputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("zhwiki-latest-pages-articles.xml");
    XMLStreamReader streamReader = inputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(in);
    Set<String> namespaces = new HashSet<>();
    int articles = 0;

    String title = null;
    String context;
    Set<String> categories = new HashSet<>();

    while (true) {
        try {
            streamReader.next();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            break;
        }
        String localName = null;
        try {
            localName = streamReader.getLocalName();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        if (streamReader.isStartElement()) {
            System.out.println(localName);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(articles + " articles");
```

This is the output

```
mediawiki
sitename
base
generator
case
namespaces
namespace
namespace
namespace
page
ns
id
revision
parentid
timestamp
contributor
id
minor
comment
text
sha1
model
format
```

Comment: am getting all start  tags with same program like.... mediawiki
siteinfo
sitename
base
generator
case
namespaces
namespace
namespace
namespace
page
title
ns
id
revision
id
parentid
timestamp
contributor
username
id
minor
comment
text
sha1
model
format
0 articles